# Redirect www traffic to non-www in nginx AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my node app on AWS beanstalk using nginx server and ubuntu. I want to redirect all my traffic from www.mydomain.in to mydomain.in. I have tried the following:-

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.your-domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://your-domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Mostly all the variations of this code i have tried and as soon as i deploy my project on Beanstalk it goes into severe condition and stops working. Is there something i am doing wrong?